# Edit gummi ".bst"

Tags: gummi

I'm using gummi and I need to change my bibliography language to spanish and I don't know how to do it. When I wrote various authors, the word "AND" appeared instead of "Y". May you tell how to find and edit ".bst" file? I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. If exist other best way, I'll appreciate an example how to do it.

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Which bibliography style are you using, i.e. what is written in `\bibliographystyle`? You can find the file using `kpsewhich nameofbibstyle.bst` in a terminal, but you should make a copy and edit that, instead of editing the original.

Comment: @Torbjørn T. Thanks by the info! but my problem has been solved on a tricky way. My bibliography style is \bibliographystyle{unsrt}

Comment: Good to hear you worked it out. Feel free to write an answer explaining how you solved it, that could be of use to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was very simple but not the correct way:

```
@book{BBDD,
author = {{Luque Ruiz, Irene y Gomez-Nieto, Miguel Ángel ET AL}},
year = 2001,
title = "Bases de datos, desde Chen hasta Codd con ORACLE",
publisher = "RA-MA Editorial, Madrid",
note = "Primera edición. ISBN: 84-7897-478-4"
}
```

If I have two authors, I’ll write them like one with my spanish conjuction **"Y"** and the field ISBN like **note** with the edition